# Data from XML to Python list

Tags: python, xml, storage

Is it possible to store data from an XML file to a list in python. For example I have an XML file with the following content:

```
<brochure>
<onlinePath>http://EEE</onlinePath>
<downloadPath>http://YYY</downloadPath>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<AAA>
    <P>JPG</P>
        <Q>JPG</Q>
</AAA>
</brochure>
<brochure>
<onlinePath>http://EKK</onlinePath>
<downloadPath>http://XXX</downloadPath>
<Name>DEF</Name>
<AAA>
    <P>JPG</P>
        <Q>JPG</Q>
</AAA>
</brochure>
```

Is it possible to store into a python list like:

```
onlinePath = ("http://EEE", "http://EKK")
Name = ("ABC", "DEF")
```

Comment: Insert all the code in the code tag.

Comment: In short, to answer your question, yes it is possible. A suggestion though: Try and reformat your question as it is difficult to read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import lxml

xml = """
<brochures>
    <brochure>
        <onlinePath>http://EEE</onlinePath>
        <downloadPath>http://YYY</downloadPath>
        <Name>ABC</Name>
        <AAA>
            <P>JPG</P>
            <Q>JPG</Q>
        </AAA>
    </brochure>
    <brochure>
        <onlinePath>http://EKK</onlinePath>
        <downloadPath>http://XXX</downloadPath>
        <Name>DEF</Name>
        <AAA>
            <P>JPG</P>
            <Q>JPG</Q>
        </AAA>
    </brochure>
</brochures>
"""

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
mylist = root.xpath('//brochure/onlinePath/text()')
```

results in

```
['http://EEE', 'http://EKK']
```

Notes:

1. I wrapped your xml in <brochures></brochures> to make it a tree instead of a forest (ie single root node);
2. If you want to read from a file instead of a string, use lxml.etree.parse() instead of lxml.etree.fromstring()

Comment: Thanks Alot mate this saved me a hell lot of time

Comment: @Rakesh: Glad to help - so - flag it as a solution!

Answer (score 4):

Hugh's solution is fine. Here is a variation that uses ElementTree (tested with Python 2.6):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse("yourfile.xml")   
olp = tree.findall("//onlinePath")
mylist = [t.text for t in olp]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible. Two libraries to help you with this is [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). Take a look at them.

Comment: @kame Then install it.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it can store it in lists bt it can store it in dictionaries since they have key:values [using expat for xml](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pyexpat.html?highlight=parsing%20xml)

but can check the entries here

Answer (score 0):

For short xml file like this, I suggest you [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: "The BeautifulSoup class is full of web-browser-like heuristics for divining the intent of HTML authors. But XML doesn't have a fixed tag set, so those heuristics don't apply. So BeautifulSoup doesn't do XML very well."
-- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML

Comment: @Tomasz Elendt: The BeautifulSoup module has a separate class - BeautifulStoneSoup - which should be used to parse XML.